# SQLServer (2012) Left Join conditions in WHERE or ON AND

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, left-join, where-clause

I have two tables that contain client IDs.  One table (**TABLE_B**) contains Contract and Service information as *Spells for clients* and the other table (**TABLE_A**) contains School Attendance information as *Evaluations for clients*. Both tables contain duplicate client IDs and are distinct by Spell and Evaluation IDs only. Not all the clients in TABLE_B are in TABLE_A but all the clients in TABLE_A are in TABLE_B .

I would like the query to produce a data set that lists all the clients (from TABLE_B) and is joined when the evaluation date falls within the spell open and close dates.  Not all spells are closed.

The query below fails because it does not contain all the client records-records where the client ID is not found in TABLE_A are omitted and the data set does not contain all the client IDS in TABLE_B.  How do I fix this?

```
SELECT
      B.[Agency]
      ,B.[Contract#]
      ,B.[total spells]
      ,B.[spell open date]
      ,B.[spell close date]
      ,B.[spell ID]
      ,B.[Class Level]
      ,B.[Spec Pop]
      ,B.[client_id] 
      ,A.[client_id] 
      ,A.[e_due_date]
      ,A.[scheduled]
      ,A.[attended]

FROM [PAK].[dbo].[TABLE_B] B 

LEFT JOIN [PAK].[dbo].[[TABLE_A] A ON A.[client_id]=B.[client_id]

WHERE  A.[e_due_date]>=B.[spell open date] AND (A.[e_due_date]<=B.[spell close date] OR B.[spell close date] IS NULL)
```

Comment: The first part of your `WHERE` statement filters out any non-null records in the second table by requiring a value in B.[spell open date]

Comment: Would Adding  OR B.[spell open date] IS NULL fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` when you apply `WHERE` logic outside of the left join criteria. You need to change your `WHERE` to an `AND` and it will work.

The `JOIN` logic will create the dataset that your `WHERE` logic applies to so any limitations in the `WHERE` logic that will filter out `NULL` values will remove the row from your end results. If you have it within your `LEFT JOIN` criteria then it will simply apply to whether or not the right side data is included in the row results or if it will be null.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked correctly by using AND to make it part of the LEFT JOIN (once I added plenty of parentheses!)